# wordpress redirect on logout

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a logout link on my wordpress page.

Here's the code:

```
echo '<a href="http://mydomain.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to='.urlencode($url_home).'&_wpnonce=a2b834fa87">Logout</a>';
```

When I click logout it still prompting me if I am sure to logout and after login out it's going to the login page.

How can I just get it to loggout and go to index.php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the built-in Wordpress functions:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_bloginfo('url') ); ?>&_wpnonce=a2b834fa87">Logout</a>
```

Comment: It's not going to the homepage. It's asking if I want to loggout and when I go it goes to the login page.... url on login is: http://mydomain/wp-login.php?loggedout=true

Comment: you put whatever you want in the brackets. `wp_logout_url("http://anydomain.com/any/page");`